# How to create a mask for x (n, m) and y (n,) shapes for multinomial logistic regression?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to run a multinomial logistic regression with an X, y and hour that should act as mask for values that I am interested in. But the shapes are different, and I can't get them to fit in the multinomial without having issues with nans.

These are the shapes and `np.unique()` prints of my arrays before I create the regression mask:

```
x :
[-717.10062214 -712.98025999 -706.55113102 ...  706.78297915  719.08540065
           nan]
y :[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5. nan]
hours : [  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.
  15.  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.  25.  26.  27.  28.
  29.  30.  31.  32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  37.  38.  39.  40.  41.  42.
  43.  44.  45.  46.  47.  48.  49.  50.  51.  52.  53.  54.  55.  56.
  57.  58.  59.  60.  61.  62.  63.  64.  65.  66.  67.  68.  69.  70.
  71.  72.  73.  74.  75.  76.  77.  78.  79.  80.  81.  82.  83.  84.
  85.  86.  87.  88.  89.  90.  91.  93.  94.  95.  96.  98.  99. 100.
 104. 105. 106. 109. 110. 119. 120. 122. 133. 160.  nan]

# Shapes

X shape: (293240, 4), Y Shape: (29324,) , h shape: (293240,)
```

These are the arrays I need. Since I need to fit them into a logistic regression, I need to remove nans and make the inputs binary to use them in train_test_split to prepare for the logistic regression, so I use a mask called regmask:

```
# Making and applying masks
regmask = np.all(np.isfinite(x),1) & np.isfinite(y) & (hours == 40)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x[regmask], y[regmask], 
                                                    test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

ERROR:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[64], line 57
     54 print(f"X shape: {x_all.shape}, Y Shape: {y.shape} , h shape: {hours.shape}")
     56 ## Making and applying masks
---> 57 regmask = np.all(np.isfinite(x_all),1) & np.isfinite(y) & (hours == 40)
     59 print(f"X masked shape: {x_all[regmask].shape}, Y masked Shape: {y[regmask].shape} , h masked shape: {hours[regmask].shape}")
     61 print(np.sum(regmask))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (293240,) (29324,)
```

And I get the error because of the different shapes, of course. But how can I remove the nans, and keep the shapes the same to fit them onto the train_test_split? Ideally, once I have solved this shapes issue, all the rest would go smoothly.

Comment: It seems like the input data are just not compatible. Can you give us the shape of `x[~np.isnan(x)]`, `y[~np.isnan(y)]` and `hours[~np.isnan(hours)]` please ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I have solved this by now. I will add the solution myself

Answer (score 0):

As they were, the arrays would never have fit together. So I found out the issue was before, when preparing the `y` and modified that to match the (293240,1) shape that would make it work with x.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).